# Using Leibniz integral rule

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations

I have found the following problem:

**By integrating both sides of an appropriate integral relationship, with suitable limits,
show that:**
$$\int_0^1\frac{x^b-x^a}{\ln(x)}dx=\ln\left[\frac{b+1}{a+1}\right]$$
I started by saying:
$$I_a=-\int_0^1x^adx=-\left[\frac{x^a}{a+1}\right]_0^1=-\frac{1}{a+1}$$
$$I_b=\int_0^1x^bdx=\left[\frac{x^b}{b+1}\right]_0^1=\frac{1}{b+1}$$
Which I believe is correct but I have not really dealt with partial differential equations so I have no idea how to proceed from here.

I believe from this we can say:
$$I=-\ln|a+1|+C$$
$$I=\ln|b+1|+C$$
so can i just combine these

Comment: Where did partial differential equations spring from? How did you come up withe the expressions for $I_a, I_b$????

Comment: Antiderivative of $x^t$ is not $x^t.$

Comment: I used leibniz integral rule to differentiate wrt $a$ and $b$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you meant by $I_a$ or $I_b$, but I think you had something like this in mind: define
\begin{equation}
I(t) = \int_0^1 \dfrac{x^t}{\ln(x)} \, dx
\end{equation}
What you're being asked to compute is $I(b) -I(a)$. Let's first use the Leibniz integral rule to compute $I'(t)$:
\begin{align}
I'(t) &= \int_0^1 \dfrac{\partial}{\partial t} \left( \dfrac{x^t}{\ln(x)} \right) \, dx \\
&= \int_0^1 \dfrac{x^t \ln(x)}{\ln(x)} \, dx \\
&= \int_0^1 x^t \, dx \\
&= \dfrac{1}{t+1}.
\end{align}

Therefore,
\begin{align}
I(b) - I(a) &= \int_a^b I'(t) \, dt \\
&= \int_a^b \dfrac{1}{t+1} \, dt \\
&= \ln \left( \dfrac{b+1}{a+1} \right),
\end{align}